# Как инициализировать js без .click?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо задать минимальную дату для календаря, сейчас она работает если нажать на кнопку.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
      <button id="setMinDate" class="btn btn-default" title="Установить минимальную дату">
        minDate("20.04.2021")
      </button>
    </div>

<!-- Инициализация Bootstrap DateTimePicker -->
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({ locale: 'ru' });
  $("#setMinDate").click(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker3').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment('20.04.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY'));
  });
});
</script>
```

Как исправить script, чтобы минимальная дата работала без клика по `button id="setMinDate"`?

```
<script>
var div = $('#ever');
    
$('.form-control').on('change', function () {
    div.text($(this).val());

$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({ locale: 'ru' });

$('#datetimepicker3').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment('20.04.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY'));

});
</script>
```

Comment: Убрать клик и оставить только строку с minDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто вызвать функцию без обработчика.

```js
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group" id="datetimepicker3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
      <button id="setMinDate" class="btn btn-default" title="Установить минимальную дату">
        minDate("20.04.2021")
      </button>
    </div>

<!-- Инициализация Bootstrap DateTimePicker -->
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({ locale: 'ru' });

    $('#datetimepicker3').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment('20.04.2021', 'DD.MM.YYYY'));
 
});
</script>
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! В вопрос снизу добавил #ever в нем дата. Реально дату из ever поместить в строку, где сейчас 20.04.2021? Спасибо.

Comment: `const everDate = $("#ever").val(); $("#setMinDate ").append(everDate)`